# Calculate tx fees before sending with sendtoaddress

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, transaction-fees, sending

I see this question [time](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/24406/deduct-fee-from-transaction-amount) and [time](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/how-to-calculate-transaction-size-before-sending) again, but I only find answers for calculating the fees in creating raw transactions.

I am using `sendtoaddress` and would like to be able to calculate the tx fee needed prior to calling the api. I would like to avoid creating a raw transaction if reasonably possible.

how might i do this using the json-rpc api? (i'm using bitcoind)

Answer (score 5):

If you call

```
bitcoin-cli settxfee <fee>
```

just before call

```
bitcoin-cli sendtoaddress "1LipeR1AjHL6gwE7WQECW4a2H4tuqm768N" <value>
```

Then the fee will be `<fee>`.

**Important note:** make sure in the graphic mode (when you start with **`bitcoin-qt`** command) the "custom" is selected, otherwise your command `settxfee` will be ignored (see image bellow).

Also, I'm not sure if this option is selected by default, and I am not sure as well if it you can set "custom" via API. If someone knows that, please edit this answer and fix it.

**Note 2:** I'm not sure if this is strictly necessary, maybe not. I didn't make many tests. The test I made was starting bitcoin with **`bitcoin-qt -txindex -server &`** and then letting the interface open. If "recommended" is selected the command **`settxfee`** will be ignored. I didn't tested e.g. what if let the "recommended" option selected, close the interface and then start with **`bitcoind -txindex`** for example.

[image]

Comment: But what if you want to use the floating recommend fee and simply get a rough approximation of it before sending the coins? The question is about calculating the fee, not setting it. I can't believe using raw transactions is the only way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but you might take a look at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/5503
It's not merged (yet) but it would give you the opportunity to get the fee before sending the transaction (with 4 steps: createrawtransaction, fundrawtransaction [get fee], signrawtransaction, sendrawtransaction)